# How can I catch WordPress custom settings page slug has already changed?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, wp-admin

I created a custom settings page like below.

```php
    add_menu_page(
      __('Management', 'domain'),
      __('Management', 'domain'),
      'activate_plugins',
      'management', // <---
      function () {
        echo 'Hello';
      },
      'icon',
      999
    );
```

As we can see, this page is accessed via the "`admin.php?page=management`" link. I commented above with "`<---`"
But this is such a page that users can change this slug.

- For example, let's make this "`management-2`" and save the form.
- In this case, WordPress redirects to "`admin.php?page=management&settings-updated=true`", but since we set it to "`management-2`", I get a "`403`" error.
- At this point I need to catch a hook, start a new redirect and return it to the "`admin.php?page=management-2&settings-updated=true`" link, but I couldn't find any hook to do this.

Does anyone have any solution suggestions?

Comment: “But this is such a page that users can change this slug” - I don’t understand what that means?

Comment: Sorry I added a picture of this. I hope it was clearer. @ChrisHaas

Comment: _Why_ would users need to change this in the first place? If you are worried that the slug might collide with other plugins or theme settings pages, then you should probably rather use some sort of prefix that is unique to your plugin or theme, something derived from the plugin/theme name ...

Comment: I cannot imagine a reason why you’d want to give your users the ability to change your plugin’s query string activator. That is _your’s_, not _their’s_. If you want additional sub-pages for them, a form like this could be used, the value stored in options, and you add_menu_page could dynamically register it based on that, but that’s a stretch even. Also, is “text domain” the translation domain? If so, there’s even less reasons to allow that to be customized by users, you would be losing features by doing that.